# History.back only when redirected to google translate

Tags: javascript, browser-history, google-translate

Is it possible to make the history.back(-2) only to work when you have pushed the translate button and redirected to google translate?

Here is my code, i have no idea where to go from here...

```
<div class="translate">
  <a href="javascript:history.go(-2)">
    <img src="wp-content/themes/crescendo/images/United-Kingdom.png" height="30" width="30">
  </a>

  <a href="http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?
depth=1&hl=en&ie=UTF8&langpair=en%7Cno&rurl=translate.google.com&u=
http://christoffersendesign.com/tam/&usg=ALkJrhgUGrRYKLL-pliCPAo61IrFfJL0jA">
    <img src="wp-content/themes/crescendo/images/Norway.png" height="30" width="30">    
  </a>
```

Comment: _The translate button_. What is the translate button? And you will be redirected TO Google Translate?

Comment: You will be redirected to google translate with the lower a href, my problem is that when you click the UK flag before you click the norwegian one, you will go back two steps in your history.@putvande Take a look: http://christoffersendesign.com/tam/

Comment: What do you mean click before? You are landing on a different website are you not? How are you getting back to yours?

Comment: I'm landing on the same site just in google translate, to get back to the main site (without translation) im using the history.go(-2).

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Can you not check for what domain you are on? Should be Google when in translate. Or otherwise you could just use the URL for the original webpage instead of `History.go(-2)`?

Comment: Already tried that, but google translate somehow adds the direct url link behind the current url, if you understand... like this: http://translate.google.com/translate?depth=1&hl=en&ie=UTF8&langpair=en%7Cno&rurl=translate.google.com&u=http://christoffersendesign.com/tam/